# win32ui: Change Font & Print Multiple Lines

Tags: python, pywin32

I am trying to print out the following on my printer:

Hello World

This

Is

A

Test

I am able to print each line, one after the other if I don't change the font. However, once I add the font, it prints out everything with each word on top of each other. How can I change the font and print multiple lines? Here is my code below:

```
import win32ui

samplePrintText = ['Hello World','This','Is','A','Test']

dc = win32ui.CreateDC()
dc.CreatePrinterDC()
dc.StartDoc('Test')
dc.StartPage()

fontdata = { 'name':'Arial', 'height':25}
font = win32ui.CreateFont(fontdata)
dc.SelectObject(font)

for i in range(len(samplePrintText)):
    dc.TextOut(0,i, samplePrintText[i])
    dc.MoveTo(0, i)
    dc.LineTo(0, i)

dc.EndPage()
```

Comment: Is it the **i** in the _for_ loop.. Perhaps the scale of **i** is very small that you see all of them printing on the same line. Can you try replacing the **i** in `dc.MoveTo(0, i)` with **i * 100** or some decent factor, & check if you get the required output...

Comment: For that matter, i has to be changed in other lines too.. TextOut & LineTo..